# XSLT : Copy whole xml document discarding specific parent nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have something like this :

```
<body>
    foo bar foo bar foo bar...
    <p>foo bar!</p>
    <div class="iWantYourContent">
        <p>baz</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want this output:

```
<body>
    foo bar foo bar foo bar...
    <p>foo bar!</p>
    <p>baz</p>
</body>
```

I have managed to get the content of the node using this :

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//x:div[@class = 'iWantYourContent']"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//x:div[@class = 'iWantYourContent']">
    <body>
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </body>
</xsl:template>
```

But i'm not able to keep the rest of the document.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do this sort of thing is typically, with an identity template that copies everything:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*" >
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

And then you make a template to match the items you want to skip over:

```
<xsl:template match="div[@class='iWantYourContent']" >
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
</xsl:template>
```

i.e. skip the copy, because you don't want the div element copies, but DO apply templates
on further elements, because you do want to copy the descendants of div.

( If you wanted to skip the contents entirely, then you would leave the template empty and have no content output at all. )

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the plain text and the `<p>` nodes, use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <!-- Suppress the xml header in output -->
  <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <body><xsl:apply-templates /></body>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p">
      <p><xsl:copy-of select="text()"/></p>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've used the commandline tool `xsltproc` for testing the stylesheet:

```
xsltproc test.xsl test.html
```

Output:

```
<body>
    foo bar foo bar foo bar...
    <p>foo bar!</p>

        <p>baz</p>

</body>
```

Comment: Actually <p> nodes were just examples. I wanted all the document except specific containers.