# How to partially transform xml using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to do some XML data migration, migrating xml documents from one schema to another updated version. The changes are not huge so I am wondering whether there is a easy way for xslt to only transform partially the xml. e.g. rename an element name only etc.

Comment: Essentially, this is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617404/xslt-copy-whole-xml-document-discarding-specific-parent-nodes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT takes an input document and creates a new output document. As for doing small changes, yes, start your stylesheet with the identity transformation template and add more specific templates for the changes e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<!-- identity transformation template -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- rename foo to bar elements -->
<xsl:template match="foo">
  <bar>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </bar>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you're using XSLT 2.0 and got lots of rules that involve renaming a single element (and no other changes), you can go one step further and define your mapping in a global variable and write a template that handles all of them.